# SQL : How to find where there are no entries in joined table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how to setup my query to get the company that have zero jobs.

```
company
- id

jobs
- id
- company_id
```

So I want a result of rows from the company that don't have any jobs.

EDIT
Sorry i mistaked myself in my question.. It also need to have the INNER JOIN from tabel jobs on tabel company (jobs.company_id=company.id)

So:
I want a result os rows from the company that doesnt have ANY jobs or has jobs non-actief (active=0).

Comment: `select t.* from company where t.id not in (select company_id from jobs)`. But I strongly recommend you to read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id 
from company 
where id not in(select company_id from jobs where active != 0)
```

Comment: Sorry i mistaked myself in my question.. It also need to have the INNER JOIN from tabel jobs on tabel company (jobs.company_id=company.id) So:
I want a result of rows from the company that doesnt have ANY jobs or has jobs non-actief (active=0).

Comment: How to check that job active, is it a column

Comment: Yes indeed. jobs.active=0.

So i want results from companies that HAVE NO JOBS ACTIVE and have NO JOBS AT ALL. Sorry for my explaination, first day of the week..

Comment: Okay but now i only get results from companies that HAVE NONACTIVE jobs, i also need the companys without any jobs

Comment: They included both of your purposes. The first select select only company has at least one active job, so the rest is the job has no active job and the job not in jobs table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.* FROM companies c 
LEFT JOIN jobs j ON c.id=j.company_id 
HAVING company_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT company.id , jobs.id
FROM company
    LEFT JOIN jobs ON jobs.company_id = company.id
WHERE jobs.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to you an outer join.

try this

```
select  count(c.id)
from company c
left join jobs j on j.companyid = c.id
where j.id is null
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what is wrong with [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12893137/722783) and what is difference between your answer and mine? because no one wants to tell me why they downvoted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try query given below:

```
SELECT * FROM company AS c WHERE c.id NOT IN (SELECT company_id FROM jobs)
```